# Using data.table to match multiple patterns against multiple strings in R

Tags: r, string, data.table, pattern-matching

```
library(data.table)
dat1 <- data.table(id1 = c(1, 1, 2),
          pattern = c("apple", "applejack", "bananas, sweet"))
dat2 <- data.table(id2 = c(1174, 1231),
          description = c("apple is sweet", "apple is a computer"),
          memo = c("bananas, sweet yes", "bananas, sweetyes"))
> dat1
   id1        pattern
1:   1          apple
2:   1      applejack
3:   2 bananas, sweet
> dat2
    id2         description               memo
1: 1174      apple is sweet bananas, sweet yes
2: 1231 apple is a computer  bananas, sweetyes
```

I have two `data.table`s, `dat1` and `dat2`. I want to search for each `pattern` in `dat2` against the `description` and `memo` columns in `dat2` and store the corresponding `id2`s.

The final output table should look something like this:

```
   id1        pattern description_match memo_match
1:   1          apple         1174,1231       <NA>
2:   1      applejack              <NA>       <NA>
3:   2 bananas, sweet              <NA>       1174
```

The regular expression I want to use is `\\b[pattern]\\b`. Below is my attempt:

```
dat1[, description_match := dat2[grepl(paste0("\\b", dat1$pattern, "\\b"), dat2$description), .(id2 = paste(id2, collapse = ","))]]
dat1[, memo_match := dat2[grepl(paste0("\\b", dat1$pattern, "\\b"), dat2$memo), .(id2 = paste(id2, collapse = ","))]]
```

However, both give me the error that `grepl` can only use the first `pattern`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We group by row sequence, create  the match columns from 'dat2', by `paste`ing the 'id2' extracted from the logical output from `grepl`

```
library(data.table)
dat1[, c("description_match", "memo_match") := {
    pat <- sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', paste(pattern, collapse = "|"))
    .(toString(dat2$id2[grepl(pat, dat2$description)]), 
    toString(dat2$id2[grepl(pat, dat2$memo)]))
   }, seq_along(id1)]
dplyr::na_if(dat1, "")
    id1        pattern description_match memo_match
   <num>         <char>            <char>     <char>
1:     1          apple        1174, 1231       <NA>
2:     1      applejack              <NA>       <NA>
3:     2 bananas, sweet              <NA>       1174
```

According to `?sprintf`

> The string **fmt** contains normal characters, which are passed through to the output string, and also conversion specifications which operate on the arguments provided through .... The allowed conversion specifications start with a **%** and end with one of the letters in the set **aAdifeEgGosxX%**

> s - Character string. Character NAs are converted to "NA".

---

Or use a `for` loop

```
for(nm in names(dat2)[-1]) 
   dat1[, paste0(nm, "_match") :=  
     toString(dat2$id2[grepl(paste0("\\b", pattern, "\\b"), 
       dat2[[nm]])]), seq_along(id1)][]
```

Comment: Thanks. What does `(%s)` mean?